# Requires Babel "^7.0.0-0", but was loaded with "6.26.0"

Tags: javascript, jestjs, babeljs, babel-jest

I have migrated my app to babel 7 beta and everything seems to work except the tests. I think I've read everything out there but I'm still getting this error:

> ● Test suite failed to run
>
> ```
> Requires Babel "^7.0.0-0", but was loaded with "6.26.0". If you are sure you have a compatible version of @babel/core, it is likely
> ```
>
> that something in your build process is loading the wrong version.
>   Inspect the stack  trace of this error to look for the first entry
>   that doesn't mention "@babel/core" or "babel-core" to see what is
>   calling Babel.
>
> ```
>   at throwVersionError (node_modules/@babel/helper-plugin-utils/lib/index.js:65:11)
>   at Object.assertVersion (node_modules/@babel/helper-plugin-utils/lib/index.js:13:11)
>   at _default (node_modules/@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties/lib/index.js:81:7)
>   at node_modules/@babel/helper-plugin-utils/lib/index.js:19:12
>       at Array.map (<anonymous>)
> ```
>
> Test Suites: 8 failed, 8 total

**babelrc**

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    "@babel/preset-react",
    "@babel/preset-flow"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    ["module-resolver", {
      "alias": {
        "static": "./static",
        "common": "./src/common",
        "data": "./src/data"
      }
    }],
    ["styled-jsx/babel", { "plugins": ["styled-jsx-plugin-sass"] }],
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import"
  ]
}
```

**devDependencies**

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.0.0-beta.49",
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0-beta.49",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.0.0-beta.49",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.0.0-beta.49",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0-beta.49",
    "@babel/preset-flow": "^7.0.0-beta.49",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0-beta.49",
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-0",
    "babel-eslint": "8.2.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.0-beta",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^3.1.1",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.19",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.1",
    "enzyme": "^3.3.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.1.1",
    ...
```

**jest.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  rootDir: '<rootDir>/../../',
  collectCoverageFrom: ['src/**/*.(jsx|js)'],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$':
      '<rootDir>/tests/fileMock.js',
  },
  setupTestFrameworkScriptFile: '<rootDir>/tests/setupTests.js',
};
```

I run it with command:

```
"test": "jest --config tests/jest.config.js",
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to have both `babel-core@^7` and `@babel/core@^7` along with `babel-jest@latest`, try adding

```
yarn add babel-jest babel-core@^7.0.0-0
```

as mentioned in here https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/5525

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it turned out I had explicitly install this package by `npm i -D babel-jest`.