# Error: Requires Babel "^7.0.0-0", but was loaded with "6.26.3"

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am using express-react-views package to render react components in serverside(NodeJs). I tried to render my react component as in the example https://github.com/reactjs/express-react-views/tree/master/examples/dynamic. But when I tried npm start, it throws an error that:
Error: Requires Babel "^7.0.0-0", but was loaded with "6.26.3". I tried upgrading babel as per the doc on https://github.com/babel/babel-upgrade. But still there is same error.

How can I fix this issue? Please help as I'm stuck on this error

My package.json file

```
{
"name": "dynamic-views",
"version": "0.1.0",
"description": "Example of creating a dynamic app using express-react- 
 views",
"author": "Chris Johnson <tenorviol@yahoo.com>",
"private": true,
"scripts": {
"start":
"browserify -t babelify views/main.js --standalone main -o 
public/main.js  && node app.js"
},
"dependencies": {
"@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0",
"@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
"babelify": "^7.3.0",
"browserify": "^14.3.0",
"express": "^4.15.3",
"express-react-views": "^0.11.0",
"react": "^16.0.0",
"react-dom": "^16.0.0"
}
}
```

My package-lock.json file

```
{
"name": "dynamic-views",
"version": "0.1.0",
"lockfileVersion": 1,
"requires": true,
"dependencies": {
"@babel/code-frame": {
"version": "7.0.0",
"resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@babel/code-frame/-/code- 
frame-7.0.0.tgz",
"integrity": "sha512-   OfC2uemaknXr87bdLUkWog7nYuliM9Ij5HUcajsVcMCpQrcLmtxRbVFTIqmcSkSeYRBFBRxs2FiUqFJDLdiebA==",
"requires": {
"@babel/highlight": "^7.0.0"
}
},
"@babel/core": {
"version": "7.4.5",
"resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@babel/core/-/core-7.4.5.tgz",
"integrity": "sha512-OvjIh6aqXtlsA8ujtGKfC7LYWksYSX8yQcM8Ay3LuvVeQ63lcOKgoZWVqcpFwkd29aYU9rVx7jxhfhiEDV9MZA==",
"requires": {
"@babel/code-frame": "^7.0.0",
"@babel/generator": "^7.4.4",
"@babel/helpers": "^7.4.4",
"@babel/parser": "^7.4.5",
"@babel/template": "^7.4.4",
"@babel/traverse": "^7.4.5",
"@babel/types": "^7.4.4",
"convert-source-map": "^1.1.0",
"debug": "^4.1.0",
"json5": "^2.1.0",
"lodash": "^4.17.11",
"resolve": "^1.3.2",
"semver": "^5.4.1",
"source-map": "^0.5.0"
}
},
```

Comment: Did you run `npm install`?

Comment: Yes. I run npm install first and then npm start

Comment: Can you post relevant snippets from your `package.json` and `package-lock.json` files?

Answer (score 0):

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50620775/requires-babel-7-0-0-0-but-was-loaded-with-6-26-0) helped a lot along with below posts for the errors that followed. :)

[Jest TypeError: Path must be a string. Received undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46220674/jest-typeerror-path-must-be-a-string-received-undefined)

[TypeError: Cannot read property 'cwd' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54707877/typeerror-cannot-read-property-cwd-of-undefined/55520511)

For me the below solution worked. I hope it works for you too!

```
yarn add babel-jest@22.4.3 --dev
yarn add jest@21.0.2 --dev
babel-core@^7.0.0-0 
                 ---> (Choose "7.0.0-bridge.0")
```